# Is it possible to upgrade the Evolution mail client to 3.16 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, evolution

Is it possible to upgrade the Evolution mail client to v3.16 in Ubuntu 14.04 without having to install the full Gnome stack?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you wish to use version 3.16?

Comment: Yes , evolution 3.16, which I use in Fedora 21 is much faster with MS Exchange (EWS) accounts compared to the one that comes in with 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do, Install it from source code:

Download evolution 3.16 source code from [here](http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/gnome/sources/evolution/3.16/evolution-3.16.0.tar.xz).

First install  dependencies

```
sudo apt-get build-dep evolution
```

Then compile it using

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I have got dependency errors for ` libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libcheese7` ,  `libclutter-gtk-1.0-dev : Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0` and  `xul-ext-webaccounts : Depends: webaccounts-extension-common`

Comment: i resolved the dependency issues but the build requires 3.16 version of `camel-1.2, libebook-1.2, libecal-1.2, libedataserver-1.2, libebackend-1.2`

Comment: hrm, i get:
apt-get build-dep evolution
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for evolution

Answer (score 0):

Yes, other option...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fta/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**Beware !**

**evolution-data-server-online-accounts** package requires dependencies not provided by this PPA...
(issues with Gmail that uses OAuth 2.0)

Comment: Thank you but does it work for 14.04?

Comment: Doesnt work in 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: This worked for me on 15.04, although I had to uninstall and reinstall evolution for the upgrade to work (problems with evolution-common). Not sure this was a good idea, I hope this does not cause (too much) issues with the upgrade to 15.10…

Comment: OP asks for 14.04

Answer (score 0):

> **evolution-data-server-online-accounts** package requires dependencies not provided by this PPA... (issues with Gmail that uses OAuth 2.0)

Delete Gmail account an recreate it did it for me (15.04 - gnome 3.14)